# Simultaneous equations - comparing units

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

The question asks you to guess a plausible formula for the volume V of the crater
produced by a surface explosion with energy E in soil of density ρ with gravitational
constant given, as usual by g, using the formula: V = k(E^a x ρ^b x g^c) for some constant k.

We use these units:

E measured in kg. m^2. sec^-2

ρ measured in kg . m^-2

g measured in m. sec^-2

Using this info, find values for a, b and c.

I started by assuming that V would be measured in m^3, and used this along with the units above in the formula.

After combining like terms, I obtained:

m^3 = k[kg^(a+b) x m^(2a-3b+c) x sec^(-2a-2c)]

I got stuck here because although I know I will have to solve the equations simultaneously at some point, I don't know what the next step would be here in terms of finding what each expression would be equal to, if that makes sense.

Comment: Compare units on both sides. What must $a+b$ be for example?

Comment: I assumed a + b = 0, and -2a - 2c = 0, which makes sense but then how does the constant k come into play here?

Comment: Assume it is dimensionless to start with then $3=2a-3b+c$ too. If your equations are inconsistent (no solution) you will probably have to make an assumption about the units of k to fix the problem.

Comment: Equate each unit's exponent on the LHS and RHS and solve. But first fix the exponent on meters, it should be $\,(2a-2b+c)\,$ not $\,(2a-\color{red}{3}b+c)\;$

Comment: @greg - Density is not measured in $\dfrac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^2}$, That is mass divided by area. You need mass divided by *volume*, which is $\dfrac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}$. The problem was mis-copied here. (There is such a thing as areal density, but it clearly is not appropriate for this.)

Answer (score 1):

$
\require{enclose}
\def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\beta} \def\g{\gamma}
\def\e{\enclose{updiagonalstrike}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\FLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Assuming the density is volumetric and not *area*$\ell$,
the equation to be balanced is
$$\eqalign{
V &= E^\a \rho^\b g^\g \\
\LR{m^3}
 &= \FLR{kg\cdot m^2}{s^2}^\a\:\FLR{kg}{m^3}^\b\:\FLR{m}{s^2}^\g \\
}$$
To cancel units of $(kg,\,s)$ which only appear on the RHS,
you must set $\;\b=\g=-\a$
$$\eqalign{
\LR{m^3}
&= \FLR{\e{kg}\cdot m^2}{\e{s^2}}^\a \FLR{m^3}{\e{kg}}^\a \FLR{\e{s^2}}{m}^\a
 = \LR{m^4}^\a \\
}$$
Solving for the remaining exponent yields
$$
\a = \frac34 \quad\implies\quad \b=\g=-\frac34
$$
This leaves $k$ as a **dimensionless** constant of proportionality.